# MySql: load data infile, Ignore rows with a null variable

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find an answer to this anywhere. I have a table with columns: VID, PhoneNo, Ext and EntryDate.

I tried making both the primary key, but it keeps allowing the rows with a blank phone number to be entered. The result is, I wind up with 10 million rows with only 1 million phone numbers. When I'm loading my files, I want it to load ONLY the ID, PhoneNo WHERE PhonoNo IS NOT NULL.

These two must be the primary key because I don't want to have multiple rows with ID=1 and PhoneNo = '555-1212'.

I have:

```
     #EntryDate = '2016-02-10';
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file."' IGNORE INTO TABLE PhoneNumbers
      (@VID, @AreaCode, @PhoneNo, @Ext, @Email)
    SET VID = @VID, PhoneNo = CONCAT(@AreaCode, @PhoneNo), Ext = @Ext, EntryDate='".$entryDate."'
```

Can't I do something like

```
 SET VID = @VID, PhoneNo = CONCAT(@AreaCode, @PhoneNo), 
Ext = @Ext, EntryDate='".$entryDate."'
WHERE @PhoneNo IS NOT NULL
```

?

I'm ripping my hair out!!! The only thing I can find is about entirely blank rows. Thank you in advance!

Comment: umm...set the phone number to a unique column rather than have a composite primary key...if you have composite primary key, it considers the 2 columns unique together so you can have lots of integer values in ID column with blanks in phone number column...by setting ID column to PK, AI that ensures that is always unique as well...then when you insert do Insert Ignore Into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done as you can see in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880818/skip-rows-in-mysql-load-data-infile-statement-when-row-has-value-x)

> No. There is an IGNORE option. However it use line numbers not inline logical comparisons.

The `IGNORE` part you are using is for handling duplicates, conditions like where clauses cannot be put here.

Even if you have the column type as `NOT NULL`, then the default value will be applied to the field.

> An attempt to load NULL into a NOT NULL column causes assignment of
>   the implicit default value for the column's data type and a warning,
>   or an error in strict SQL mode. Implicit default values are discussed
>   in Section 11.7, “Data Type Default Values”.

See [MySQL Documentation LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) which also quotes

> The REPLACE and IGNORE keywords control handling of input rows that
>   duplicate existing rows on unique key values:

**EDIT**

Since you haven't posted sample data, will neither assume or not that the `NULL` values appear as either empty strings or the string `"NULL"`. If it's the latter, then see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3928/mysql-load-data-infile-handling-unescaped-null-in-infile-or-creating-infile) on DBA on how to handle `NULL` as a string with `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't the answer I was looking for, but it seems to be correct in that it's not possible.

Comment: Is there a large amount of data in the text file? how is it formatted/delimeted? There still maybe other solutions, would you post a sample of the data and also give a rough guide as to how many rows each file is likely to contain?

Comment: There is a MASSIVE amount of data in the files. 68 files contain every voter in the State of Florida, and I have 68 files for each every other month since 2012. Using INNODB, that leaves a huge file when you insert it all and then delete the blank rows.

Comment: Wow that is large, it is a shame that load data Infile is the only realistic option. I would recommend running an 'optimise table' command after running the delete blank process. That should take care of the file size. Also removing indexes before insert, and then recreating them after. This will ensure they are as efficient as possible too.

Comment: Given the size of it you've done a pretty good job at the performance. I just typed `David` in the first name and searched on that. It only took a couple of seconds to retrieve retults. Looks like your indexes are good. If you're worried about the performance and the hammer on the database as it grows you should look at adding memcached to the application layer to save frequently used results in key value pairs.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty fast. In fact, try someone in Palm Beach County. Use John Dougan on 7570 Windermere (my dad). The server calculates the closest 10 neighbors based on latitude and longitude... but to do it, it has to calculate the distance from a huge number of people and return the top 10. Server is a dual G34, 16  core machine with 40 gigs of ram. It's Win2012R2 and Ubuntu Server sitting under my television (also use it for movies). I'm going to look into Memcached! Thanks!!!